# Filtering in a Datagrid component with custom queries - react-admin

Tags: filter, datagrid, react-admin

I have a datagrid component that uses a custom query but I need to use filtering functionality just like the  component has.

Like this:
[Filter React-admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgB4O.jpg)

it's possible? I don't use  because I can't -or i dont´now- use Json Data for both components of this page.

My code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {List, Datagrid} from 'react-admin';

export const ArtEstadisticaDetalleList = (props) => {
   const [StateArticulo, setStateArticulo] = useState('');
   let location = useLocation()
   let IdArticulo = props.location.detail
   const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
   const [StateData, setStateData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    dataProvider.getList(
        'ArtEstadisticaDetalle',
        {
            filter: {
                art: IdArticulo,
            },
            sort: {field: 'id', order: 'DESC'},
            pagination: {page: 1, perPage: 100},
        },)
        .then(({data}) => {
            setStateData(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error Catch")
            console.log(error)
        })
}, []);

// i want to use this
const **MFiltro** = (props, data, ids, baspath) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        {/*<VerTotales label="Totales" props={props} alwaysOn/>*/}
        <QuickFilter source="mensual" label="Mensual" defaultValue={90}/>
        <QuickFilter source="trimestral" label="Trimestral" defaultValue={90}/>
        <QuickFilter source="anual" label="Anual" defaultValue={90}/>
    </Filter>
);

const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(15);
const [sort, setSort] = useState({field: 'id', order: 'ASC'})

return (
    <div>
        <div style={{margin: '1em'}}>
            <GraficoBarrasLineaBasica
                wp_data_x={StateData}
            />
            <br/>
            <Datagrid
                data={keyBy(StateData, 'id')}
                ids={StateData.map(({id}) => id)}
                currentSort={sort}
                setSort={(field, order) => setSort({field, order})}
                // <Filter {...props}>
                filter={{ paramFilter: 2 }} 
            >
                <TextField label="Artículo" source="art"/>
                <TextField label="CPT" source="t_cpt"/>
                ...
            </Datagrid>
        </div>
    </div>
)};    
export default ArtEstadisticaDetalleList;
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using eiher the `List` or the `ListBase` components?

Comment: If i use a List component, how could I assign it data-state?

Initially i try using <List> but it´s gets automatically the json from the controller (I use grails) and I couldn't resolve how to use the same json ​​also to sent to the 2nd component that shows the graphics.  Thanks for your time

Comment: Is the second component in the same page? Is it embedded in the List? We need more details about your use case to help you

Comment: Yes, the 2nd component is in the same page. Not embedded in the List.  From my code of the original post, components are <GraficoBarrasLineaBasica> and <Datagrid>. Boths use the same Json (StateData)